# How do I remove the whole many-to-many relation with custom property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I am using an entity similar to one described [here](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties). When I delete values from `post.postToCategories`, TypeORM does not delete the whole row with record, but sets one of the sides of the relation to `null` – detaching the issue.

How do I delete the whole row?

Comment: https://typeorm.io/#/relations/cascades

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks, but cascades won't work – they remove the row only when one of the records is deleted, but in my case the records stay in db, only detached.

Comment: I looked over this again and I believe what you're describing is odd. Typically one wouldn't access that many-to-many to remove a many to many association. In other words, you would remove a category from `post.categories`, not `post.postsToCategories`

Comment: See here https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/deleting-many-to-many-relations

Comment: I totally agree that this is odd! But this is the way it seems to work with many-to-many relations with custom properties. check [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1286). I am looking for a workaround...

Comment: But look at the example I linked. It says to remove it from categories

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same, I am not working with the linking table directly

Answer (score 3):

Although it is too late, but I am keeping the solution here for someone else who encounters same issue with **deleting connections for many-to-many relationships that include custom properties**.

Considering there are 2 entities `User` and `Post` having their many-to-many connection entity with custom properties named UserPost:

```
const user_post_connections: UserPosts[] = await this.userPostRepository.find(
  {
    where: {
      user: user,
    },
  },
);
if (user_post_connections?.length) {
  await this.userPostRepository.remove(user_post_connections);
}
```

NOTE: This solution is strictly for the case mentioned in this question with [this](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties) setup reference.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixable with the `orphanedRowAction` option. Assuming you have a `PostConnections` join table that joins a `user` and a `post`, you can add `orphanedRowAction: 'delete'` to each `ManyToOne` relation like so:

```
  @ManyToOne(
    () => User,
    (user) => user.postConnections,
    { orphanedRowAction: 'delete' },
  )
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Post,
    (post) => post.postConnections,
    { orphanedRowAction: 'delete' },
  )
  post: Post;
```

Comment: The `orphanedRowAction` was designed to work with `OneToMany` relations. The question was about `ManyToMany` with custom `JoinTable`, where the row in the junction table need to be removed, not the other entity.